# How can i use if condition in Laravel eager loading?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to check a field value in eloquent loading like this:

```
$query->with(['subject' => function($query){
    if('subject.is_free' != 1) {
        $query->with('file');
    }
}]);
```

I want to get file for just subjects that subject.is_free == 1

Thanks

Comment: i want to get file for just subjects that subject.is_free == 1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i cant undrestand please note a sample code thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eager load the file relation where subject relation is free, you can use the `whereHas()` method.

```
$query->with(['subject', 'file'])->whereHas('subject', function ($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->where('is_free', 1);
})->get();
```

This will give you all intances of your model that have a free subject, with the file relation loaded.

**If you want to only eager load file relation when subject is free then you must make 2 queries and merge them.**

```
$query->with('subject')->whereHas('subject', function ($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->where('is_free', 0);
})->get();
```

Then you can merge the results using Laravel collection `merge()`.

Comment: Ok, it just looks like it in your question because you are trying to eager load the file relation inside your subject subquery. So first solution should work, I will update my answer to remove second solution.

Comment: i want all subjects free or not; free by file others wothount file; it's work? @Robert Kujawa

Comment: I believe you would have to make 2 queries for that, the first one like I showed you and the second one must be to retrieve all subjects that are not free, without loading the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->whereHas('subject', function($q) {
    $q->where('is_free', true);
})->....
```

Using `whereHas` filters the results by a relationship.

Comment: i want all subjects free or not; free by file others wothount file @Commander